# Can I know the pros,cons and Limitations of Durable streaming feature of salesforce?

Tags: api, configuration, streaming-api

I wanted to Know what are Pros, cons, and limitations of Durable streaming API 37.0 in sfdc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no cons, except for the fact that extra code has to be written to take advantage of the new feature. The pro is that you can retrieve missed messages and replay them. The limitations of durable streaming are documented in [Message Reliability](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/using_streaming_api_stateless.htm); messages are only retained for 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Few things which I came across when I worked with Streaming api is

Cons:
As you know push topics triggered when DML occurs, but for merge records(in case if you are working with Account or Contacts), Subscriber get two push topics separately, i.e., one as UPDATE and another one as DELETE. But subscriber wont get to know which one was actual wining and loosing record in one pushTopic itself.

Subscriber may loose the connections at times. Subscriber(Client application) has to write a connection status check code which should run 24/7 to check the connection status. If it is dropped, Client should establish the connection again.

You don't have control in modifying the pushTopics(customizing the JSON request)

Hope this will help you.